# Python consumer application with database

Tags: python, mysql, database, windows, installation

I want to implement a simple application (for Windows), mainly for data collection and I should be able to run some queries.

I can produce an exe file from the python code, but I don't want to install the database separately, rather I'd include it in an installer. I think some other applications do the same or they require MySQL to be installed -- not in development mode -- since I saw in Windows' Programs and Features that there are some MySQL installations.

So my question is: Is there a way to use MySQL or a specific preparation method of an application so I am able to use some database operations inclusive saving data? Remark: any database would work, I was referring to MySQL because I suspect I saw some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to make an exe out of your database and Python file. Python natively supports [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) so you don't have to install anything extra if you use that.

Comment: This sounds reassuring, thanks! I'll leave the question open for a few more days, maybe there will be other suggestions.